# How to use new syntax

Tags: c++

When I am reading some article i found this line is so cryptic.

```
new (new_ptr + i) T(std::move(old_ptr[i]));
```

Can somebody explains how this syntax works?

Comment: Sure, after you have read a good C++11 tutorial and still haven't understood it.

Comment: That is placement new and isn't new in C++11

Comment: might be worth mentioning that `new T(rhs)` is (and always has been) the same as `new (::operator new(sizeof(T)) T(rhs)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What uses are there for "placement new"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new)

Comment: @FredOverflow : agreed, since i am not aware of the name, i asked this question !!!!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its a placement.

```
new (new_ptr + i) T(std::move(old_ptr[i]));
```

Here we can simplify this to:

```
new (<destinationLocation>) T(<constructor parameters);
```

This is normall C++03 and basically allows you to create an object dynamically in an area of memory that you have pre-allocated (its an advanced technique that most people will not use (unless they are building their own container like objects)).

The std::move() part is from C++11 and is creating a special reference type that allowes the move constructor to be used in the type T.

```
new T(std::move(<source Obj>));
```

This basically says create a new T using the source object and use the move constructor for effeciency. This means the 'source Obj' will be left in an undefined state (thus not usable) after the move but it allows from efficient object creation.

Combining the two you get placement new with move construction using an element from an array as the source object.

Answer (score 12):

Well, the good news is, none of it is new syntax (but all of it is `new` syntax, ho ho!). There is a function being used that was introduced in C++11, `std::move`, but that's it.

The syntax of the line is known as *placement `new`* and has been around for a good while. It allows you to create an object at some *already allocated* space in memory. Here, the memory that is already allocated is given by the pointer `new_ptr + i`. The type of the object being created there is a `T`.

A simple and pointless example of placement new is:

```
int* p = new int(); // Allocate and initialise an int
new (p) int(); // Initialise a new int in the space allocated before
```

The constructor of `T` is being passed `std::move(old_ptr[i])`. Assuming `old_ptr` points at objects of type `T`, this move allows the *move constructor* of `T` to be used to create the object. It basically pretends that `old_ptr[i]` is a temporary `T` object (even if it may not actually be), allowing the new `T` to steal from it. To learn more about this, look up [move semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/can-someone-please-explain-move-semantics-to-me).